# Is $ \mathbb{P}^n( \mathbb{C}) $ with Fubini metric $(n+1)$-points homogeneous?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry

My professor gave this definition:

> A Riemannian manifold (M,g) is said to be (n+1)-points homogeneous if for any two points $x,y \in M$ and any two orthonormal sets of tangent vector $ \{u_1,...,u_n\} \subset T^1_x(M)$ $\{v_1,..,v_n\} \subset T^1_y(M)$, there exists an isometry $f: M \to M$ such that:
>
> 1. $ f(x)=y $
> 2. $ d_xf(u_i)=v_i \ \forall i $

Now I already proved that $ \mathbb{P}^n( \mathbb{C})$ is 2-points homogeneous.
I know that it is not $(n+1)$-points homogeneous but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks for the attention

Comment: In fact, for $n\geq 2$, $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{C})$ is not even $3$-point homogeneous.  To see this, try to prove that a $3$-point homogeneous space has constant sectional curvature.   On the other hand, one can show $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$ is $(n+1)$-points homogeneous for all $n$ (noting that this is vacuously true for $n\geq 3$ since one cannot find an orthonormal set of $n \geq 3$ vectors at a point in $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C}).$)